# Accessing element from same layout parent

Tags: android, listview

i have a listview with different components (2 linear layouts and a button) , what i want to do is when i click on a button that's inside one of those linear layouts , i want to access a textview that's inside the other linearlayout , is it possible ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listV2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/textCname"
                android:textSize="21dp"

                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numero"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textColor="@color/textCother"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ville"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/textCother"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/remove"
                android:onClick="contactRemove"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/edit"
                android:onClick="contactEdit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:onClick="contactCall"
                android:id="@+id/call"
                android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

what i want to do is access the value of                 `android:id="@+id/numero"`
when i click on one of the image views

Comment: what do you mean by access textview? what are you trying to achieve with textview.

Comment: by having multiple elements since i'm using a listview , i want to use that textview's text to access the sqlite database and remove the value associated with it

Answer (score 1):

You can set `OnClickListener` interface provided by View class. Something like this.

Implement listener on your activity class

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    View.OnClickListener
```

Declare class level variables for your views

```
private TextView tvNumero;
private ImageView ivRemove, ivEdit, ivContactCall;
```

Find initialise value in `onCreate()` method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gildi_spinner);

    tvNumero = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numero)
    ivRemove = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.remove);
    ivEdit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    ivContactCall = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.contactCall);

    ivRemove.setOnClickListener(this);
    ivEdit.setOnClickListener(this);
    ivContactCall.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Implemented class from `Onclickistener`, where you get on click event for your registered views

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.remove:
        case R.id.edit:
        case R.id.contactCall:
            Toast.makeText(this, tvNumero.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

**NOTE** : `tvNumero.getText().toString()` gives you the *value of your desired* `TextView`.

**UPDATE** :

- Firstly replace your `ListView` with `RecyclerView`

Refer [RecyclerView Example](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) tutorial.

- Secondly to achieve onClick for your listed items

Refer [recyclerview-onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick) tutorial.

Comment: the thing is , i'm using a viewlist so using that gives me only the first line

Comment: Can you add graphical representation of your layout?

Comment: You want to access onClick of ListView items, right?

Comment: Check the updated answer, refer those two links & problem will be solved. Happy Coding...

Answer (score 1):

Pass context when you create your adapter, Use that context to get the inflated view.

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this);
```

Then in Adpater Class constructor :

```
public Adapter(Context context){
context.findViewById(R.id.textview);//consider this as numero textview
}
```

Then access it as per your requirement. Hope it helps!

Comment: but is this numero 1 or 2 or 3 ? like which " numero" from the listview is this